# Can you implement Accessibility methods inside UIViewController class?

Tags: ios, iphone, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I implement the Accessibility delegate methods inside a UIViewController subclass and I put a breakpoint in these delegate methods, but it never hits the breakpoint. What is the reason for this? Please let me know if anyone has an idea about this.

Answer (score 1):

Methods in the `UIAccessibility` protocol are intended to  describe *accessible, on-screen elements*, not logical blocks of code or whole screens. Accessibility clients will query your user interface for descriptions, so you will want to implement the protocol on `UIView` subclasses.

Please consider browsing the [Accessibility Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Introduction/Introduction.html) for an introduction to the accessibility APIs on iOS.

Comment: when what I did didn't work, I tried to create a subclass of a UICollectionView and the placed a breakpoint in one of the accessibility delegate methods, it never hit that either..I am writing these in swift, I don't know if writing in swift makes any difference.

Comment: There is no difference with Swift. As a container for other views, `UICollectionView` is treated differently by VoiceOver and other accessibility clients. To experiment, add a bare `UIView` to your app window and override its description. Now turn on VoiceOver and select it.